# why putting ()=>clearTimeout(timeout) in the return

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wanted to clearTimeout after setTimeout has done its job. I saw the code below and could not understand why putting `()=>clearTimeout(timeout)` in return would work.

```
const fun1=()=>{
    const timeout=setTimeout(()=>console.log('1'),1000)
    return ()=>clearTimeout(timeout)
}
fun1()
```

I realize if I rewrite fun1 like this:

```
const fun1=()=>{
    const timeout=setTimeout(()=>console.log('1'),1000)
    clearTimeout(timeout)
}
```

timeout would be cleared immediately so that '1' would never show in my console. So I guess the line of return would be executed after setTimeout has done its job. However, when I change the code to

```
const fun1=()=>{
    const timeout=setTimeout(()=>console.log('1'),1000)
    return 3
}
fun1()
```

my console output 3 before 1. I got a bit confused... Does anyone know how it works?

Comment: It returns *a function with which you can cancel the timeout if you want to.*

Comment: Your first option returns a function that clears the timeout, e.g. `const clear = fun1()` allows you to call `clear()` to clear the timeout whenever is suitable.

Comment: [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#return_value) returns an id of itself and [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout) use that to clear it.

Comment: `setTimeout` schedules the function that you pass to it, to run after the timeout expires. It doesn't block the rest of the code from running while waiting for the timeout. Otherwise you would never be able to run any other JavaScript while the timeout is counting down... So you schedule a timeout, the code continues and returns `3` and then after 1 second the function passed to `setTimeout()` is invoked and it logs `1`.

Comment: Also it's not clear to me what you mean by "_I wanted to clearTimeout after setTimeout has done its job_". `setTimeout` runs exactly once. There is no need to clean anything up after that. The only reason why you would want to clear a timeout, is if you want to abort the timeout before it occurs.

Comment: @DBS So fun1() would never run `clearTimeout(timeout)`, it just returns a function for future use?

Comment: That is correct, your first example never executes the `clearTimeout` itself.